# Can I find the shortest path via Z3

Tags: z3

I'm a beginner with Z3. I just have tried some of the  examples released in Z3 package, and I have no the other experience any more. I am working with a problem about  shortest path in a graph. Can I do it by Z3 ? Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can express such queries in logic, but maybe you can just use a dedicated algorithm (Dijktra or variants) for such problems. 
For an introduction to using Z3, take a look at the tutorial linked from 
http://rise4fun.com/z3

Comment: I've read through that material. I know that Z3 is very flexible and is able to solve many complicated problems. I want to learn more theory about Z3, However it seems like there is no information about basic mechanism or introduction . Can you tell me how I can learn more ?